# calcuulate time between background and foreground of your iphone application?

Tags: iphone, timeout, multitasking

i have a problem with multitasking. i should know how many seconds passed after iphone puts my application to background. i try to use `applicationDidEnterBackground` and `applicationWillEnterForeground` with NSDate objects but cannot get the time successfully.

Can any one help me with this?

Edit:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

    backgroundDate = [NSDate date];
    NSLog(@"background time= %@", backgroundDate);

}


- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    //– timeIntervalSinceNow

    NSLog(@"background time2= %@", backgroundDate);

    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSLog(@"foreground time= %@", date);

}
```

Logs:

> ```
> 2011-03-23 12:47:58.405 Sanal Market[1783:207] background time= 2011-03-23 10:47:58 +0000
>
> 2011-03-23 12:48:00.730 Sanal Market[1783:207] background time2= <CAContextImpl: 0x5416e10>
>
> 2011-03-23 12:48:00.731 Sanal Market[1783:207] foreground time= 2011-03-23 10:48:00 +0000
> ```

Comment: i think serhats wants to know how to get time duration passed between applicationDidEnterBackground and  applicationWillEnterForeground events.

Comment: that is rgiht Vaibhav Tekam. the problem is i do not know how to do it.

Comment: show us what you've tried (edit your answer with the code) and we will help you correct it.

Comment: Just a thought, save the date entry when applicationWillEnterForeground and compare it when the  application is active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to retain the backgrounddate, `[NSDate date]` returns a autoreleased object, and this is gone after the autorelease pool has been drained.

try

```
[backgroundDate release];
backgroundDate = [[NSDate date] retain];
```

or create a property and use the setter. `self.backgroundDate = [NSDate date];`

---

If you want to calculate the time even if the app was forced to quit from the operation system while it was in the background you should save the date to NSUserDefaults:

```
// save date in userdefaults
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"goingToBackGroundDate"];

// get date back to calculate time in background
NSDate *goingToBackGroundDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"goingToBackGroundDate"];
```